# Move Our Google Cloud SQL Instance to Compute Engine

Tags: postgresql-9.6, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

We are running several Cloud SQL Instances on GCP and plan to move all of them to some Compute Engine instances, depending on the applications that use it. Our main concern is cost of the server.

We are stil using PostgreSQL 9.6 (and have a plan to upgrade to 12.x in a few months).

I looked into [Jetware with PostgreSQL 9.6](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/jetware/postgresql96) and thinking it may be the best solution. My questions are:

0. What kind of things we must consider when selecting an image / compute engine instance on GCP? Again, our main concern is the cost of Cloud SQL instance, so the performance should come second.
1. Is there any documentation I can read that recommends a non-managed services rather than a "sponsored" article that leads us to choose the more expensive Cloud SQL Instance? Yes, we must admit that it is easy to manage, etc. But again, for now, our main concern is to reduce our server cost. We have used GC SQL Instance for about 5 years.

Thank you.